# HTML Playing audio on alert pop up box

Tags: javascript, html

is there a way to combine
`<audio controls>` in html and `alert("")` in js or `constant song = new audio()` in js so that when i press a `<button>`, a alert page will pop up with a player for me to play audio file from it ?

Comment: alerts in js are not meant for that. You can use modals. Try bootstrap or material ui modals and put the audio file in that. On pressing the button, you can open the modal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for. But you can't use alert to achieve this.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    setTimeout(
        function open(event){
            document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
        },
        1000
    )
});


document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-color: #581845;
}
.popup{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup button{
    display: block;
    margin:  0 0 20px auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #c5c5c5;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.popup p{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 20px 0;
    line-height: 25px;
}
audio{
  margin:20px;
}
a{
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0f72e5;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
        <button id="close">&times;</button>
        <h2>This Is The audio</h2>
       <audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
        <a href="#">Let's Go</a>
    </div>
```